# Jquery auto submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. I want when I click an h1 tag, then h1 tag id add in input value and Submitted automatically. But auto submits is not working.
If I click submit button then its submitted data.

```
   <h1 id="my-id">sadasdsa</h1>
<form action="" method="POST" id="aweberform">
    <p><input type="text"  name="countrycode"  value="" id="country"></p>
    <button type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1', function () {
    //alert(this.id);
    $("h1").text(this.id);
    $("input").val(this.id);
    $("#aweberform").submit();       
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#aweberform").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$(document).on('click', 'path', function () {
```

what is `path` here?

you have to use either id, class, name of the attribute as a `selector`, but in your case there is nothing with `path` in html. So change `path` to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-id', function () {
```

and try again.

Comment: sorry its my mistake, but still not working auto submit

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simpler approach as your button type is `submit`. Allot an id to it and on document click programmatically click on it.

```
<button type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn" id="submitBTN">Submit</button>
```

THE JS:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#submitBTN").click();
});
```

Whatever be the event if you want to submit the form, you can always follow the above mentioned approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just update `#my-id` instead of path:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#my-id', function () {
    //alert(this.id);
    $("h1").text(this.id);
    $("input").val(this.id);
    $("#aweberform").submit();       
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#aweberform").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="my-id">sadasdsa</h1>
<form action="" method="POST" id="aweberform">
    <p><input type="text"  name="countrycode"  value="" id="country"></p>
    <button type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry its my mistake, but still not working auto submit

Answer (score 0):

In Your JQuery You mention You mention `path` but what is that

just simply change that into id of `h1 tag` So changes are as follows

**$(document).on('click', '#my-id', function () {**

Running Example

```js
$(document).on('click', '#my-id', function () {
    //alert(this.id);
    $("h1").text(this.id);
    $("input").val(this.id);
    $("#aweberform").submit();       
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#aweberform").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="my-id">sadasdsa</h1>
<form action="" method="POST" id="aweberform">
    <p><input type="text"  name="countrycode"  value="" id="country"></p>
    <button type="submit"  name="submit"  class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry its my mistake, but still not working auto submit.

Comment: what exactly You want 'Auto submit means'

Comment: When I click h1, then this h1 tag id input into input value and Submited from automatically. I want all works done with one click